# Set the currency symbol when writing with xlsxwriter

Tags: python, excel, currency, number-formatting, xlsxwriter

I'm having trouble writing the currency symbol I want in my currency values with `xlsxwriter`.

I followed the tutorial [here](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial02.html) and I'm able to write out currency values with the correct formatting and a dollar sign (whether this is from the tutorial or excel's default settings I'm not sure).

This works:

```
money = workbook.add_format({'num_format':'$#,##0.00'})
```

And it prints out a currency value with the dollar sign.

```
$1,000.00
```

But if I try to insert my own currency, let's say `R`:

```
money = workbook.add_format({'num_format':'R#,##0.00'})
```

I get this:

```
R1000
```

How can I set the currency symbol using xlsxwriter?

Comment: What do you see if you remove the `R`?  `1000` or `1,000.00`?  What if you put a space after the R, or place the R after the numbers?

Comment: `1,000.00`, `1000`, `1000`, respectively.

Comment: Yes, the `R` and formatting disappears, wierd.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please try:

```
num_format('"R" #,##0.00')
```

[format.set_num_format()](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html)

Comment: How to add a similar check for numbers with varying sizes like R 1,000 and R 1,24,546. I'm trying like this but it isn't working-<br />
 num_format('"R" #,##0;[>=100000]"R" #,##,##0')
Btw, you might want to update the link in your answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Try something like the following:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('money_format.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

money_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '[$R]#,##0.00'})

worksheet.write('A1', 1234.56, money_format)

workbook.close()
```

The best way to determine the number format that you need is to format the cell in Excel and then edit it and look at what the custom format is.

It may be something like `[$R-431]#,##0.00` or something quite complicated if positive and negative values are handled differently.

Update: See also the [Number Format Categories](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#number-format-categories) section of the XlsxWriter Format docs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I haven't tested it with negative values, I'll have a look.

Comment: Yes, it is a locale code. That's why I'd recommend getting the correct format string directly from Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Perfectly working in all version

```
currency_id = fields.Many2one('res.currency', 'Currency',default=lambda self: self.env.user.company_id.currency_id)

style5 = xlwt.easyxf('font:bold True;', num_format_str=self.currency_id.symbol + '#,##0.00')
```